# How can a person do further academic research if their PhD degree is old?

Tags: postdocs, humanities, eu

There is a certain rule that if your PhD degree is more than 6–7 years old, you cannot apply for a postdoc position.

Suppose a physically and mentally 100% fit 70-year-old person obtained his PhD degree in 1996 from Southeast Asia. He then worked as a teacher in two tertiary public institutions for 21 years, and he is now retired from public service.

Now he wants to get involved in academic research again in the EU.

How can he do that? Can he get paid for the research?

Comment: I presume that a significant part of the question is meant to be "how can they get paid for such work?"? Visas? Can you clarify?

Comment: It would help to specify / link to that "rule". I have not heard anything like this in Austria, Sweden, or Switzerland. That said, being beyond the legal retirement age at the time of application may raise completely different employment-related issues.

Comment: If you want to get paid, you need to find the payer first. Thus, this becomes a shopping question.

Comment: The help center urges to ask only practical questions based on actual problems you face. I somewhat doubt that is the case here.

Comment: In the USA, one could not discriminate based on age in the hiring process. That said, a 21-year time period without research output will count against them, whether they were 50 or 70 years old - they would likely be at a disadvantage relative to other applicants to a job posting.

Comment: For all the people doubting the 7-8 years requirements: please note that it is written in the Official guidelines for MSCA Postdoc, therefore this requirement has already or will trickle down to any postdoc offer in Europe:
https://rea.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2023-06/Guide%20for%20applicants_MSCA%20PF%202023%20rev%202.1%20.pdf (page 8. oh the irony ... )

Comment: To the OP: based on your questions over the last three years, I share @BryanKrause's doubt that this question is "based on actual problems you face". At least, the example that you have chosen to illustrate the question does not fit with the information you have volunteered on previous questions.

Comment: @YemonChoi, are you stalking me?

Answer (score 5):

There are places where post-docs are reserved for recent graduates and aren't open to older, more experienced, people. There are exceptions, I suspect, but it would be a hard case to make.

If you can't get a regular position at some university, there is the possibility that you could teach as an adjunct (low pay, few benefits) but use the contact to get yourself involved with the full-time faculty and connect to their research.

I've known people to do this in the US, but, for them, money wasn't an object, since they had regular positions. But they used the adjunct relationship just as I suggest and were considered part of the community. Not a lot of people like this, but a few.

But, being retired, you may be secure enough financially to make something like this work.

Comment: In the German system the closest thing to an adjunct would be a Lehrauftrag. However, I don't know if that would be the best way if you are interested in research.

Answer (score 5):

I think the 'getting paid' part is close to impossible. At age 70 in the EU the general assumption is that you are retired. Getting any regular paid work contract will be very difficult and come with legal hurdles.

If you care more about getting involved with research this sounds a lot more feasible. As a start lectures and advanced seminars are usually open to the public (sometime you can get a kind of 'no-degree student id' that lets you attend these). This allows you to learn about the current research and get to know the professors. From there you can try to get involved in some joint research projects if you can convince the professors you have something useful to contribute.

Answer (score 3):

I've not seen the 6-7 years after PhD to say you can never get funded. That time limit usually applies for certain fellowships or certain grants/funding sources, and even then there is usually simply a different level of funding to apply for rather than prohibiting getting any funding.
But still, post-docs that's are funded by the University/professor's grants usually wouldn't have this limit. There may also be a limit that you can't be on a temporary contract (i.e. already being a post-doc) for more than X years at the same place/country.

I would double-check the wording of the limit, at the very least it's not a common limit so there are likely other places you could do a post-doc that would not have that limit. However, you may need to move further away to do so.

Your best chance is simply to reach out to people who are interested in working with you. Maybe they can give you a "different" job title to avoid the limits or they would know of other schemes you could apply for.

Comment: "Post-doc means a researcher who was awarded their Ph.D. or its foreign counterpart no more than 7 years before the date of starting the mobility. The period may be extended by the period of maternity and parental leave, long-term illness (more than 90 days), care for a family member (more than 90 days), pre-attestation preparation and military service. If the selected person has not obtained a Ph.D."
Just one of the hundred formulations of the same concept present in 99% of european PostDoc announcmenets in the past 5 years
https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu/jobs/53311

Comment: @EarlGrey That must be a field specific thing. I've never seen such a statement in any post-doc announcement in my field.

Comment: @TimRias We are talking about Europe, right? Since the guidelines for MSCA postdoc ask for something similar: 


"MSCA Postdoctoral Fellowships are open to postdoctoral researchers from all over the world, with a maximum of 8 years of research experience after their PhD."

the field specific thing is *in your field* and most,likely the same requirement will appear in the next few years.

MSCA rules: https://euraxess.ec.europa.eu/worldwide/australia-nz/news/msca-postdoctoral-fellowships-2023-six-steps-prepare-your-application

Comment: Page 8 of the official European definition of Psotdoc requirements for MSCA felowhisps: https://rea.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2023-06/Guide%20for%20applicants_MSCA%20PF%202023%20rev%202.1%20.pdf

Comment: @EarlGrey Grants (like MSCA) come with a variety of requirements on mimimal and maximal experience. (Note that until recently MSCA did not have a maximum experience cap). What is rare (in any field I am familiar with) is for advertised post-doc positions come with an experience cap.

Comment: @TimRias even outside EU but in Europe, maximal experience requirements for post-doc are extremely common, see this sum-up for Swiss programs : https://www.epfl.ch/campus/associations/list/polydoc/page-150985-en-html/page-151013-en-html/page-151022-en-html/ (simply look for the words "up to").
Your experience is just some anedoctal points. There is a systematic process acting at the "personel management level" of organizing the R&D proccess (please note: I do not agree with this bureaucratization process and its consequences, but it is there and being blind to it will be painful).

Comment: I worked as a PhD in a UK university who had an "early retired" (i.e. from teaching) professor who stilll came in daily to do and supervise research in his field. He was ~ 63. One of his old friends around his age or possibly older was working with him for over a year on one project. He had worked in industry labs in the same field for many years. I don't know his job title but even if he didn't get a fellowship I'm pretty sure he was a paid Senior Research Assistant at least. So unless the "Fellow" title is important to you, this is a route back into work in academia.

Comment: @EarlGrey Looking at the the most recent advertisements for post-docs in the Netherlands (https://www.academictransfer.com/en/jobs/?vacancy_type=scientific&q=&function_types=2&order=&page=1) I see only one that makes any requirement on the recency of the PhD. Maximal experience caps for post-docs are not nearly as ubiquitous as you arrogantly claim.

Comment: @TimRias you are comparing peanuts (some tens of positions open, and this in one of the most research oriented countries in EU) with programs that covers hundreds if not thousands of post doc positions (MSCA alone provides about 1000 postdoc fellowship per year).
I am not interested in discussing anedoctes, I know of a couple of people being hired as full professor in universities in Europe while not having neither the experience nor a PhD title, I leave discussing the external to 3-sigma event discussion to finance , rare disease and climatology professionals, thanks.

Comment: @EarlGrey All the "evidence" you have provided is for fellowships and grants, not advertised post-doc positions. At least a gave something which can be assumed to be a statistically representative sample. Maybe your experience is not as representative as you think.

Comment: @TimRias who cares about my experience? we are discussing a general theme, and general is determined by the statistics of it. You provided 10s of cases, I provided you 1000s. The largest PD funder in the Netherlands is NWO. Their program Veni/VIdi provides about 200 Postdocs per year. Guess what?
The Veni round 2023 is open [...] obtained their PhD a maximum of three years before 01.01.23 
The Vidi is open [...] their PhD no more than 8 years bf 1.10.23
The Vici is open [...] their PhD no more than 15 years bf 1.03.2023
https://www.nwo.nl/en/researchprogrammes/nwo-talent-programme/faq

Comment: @EarlGrey Again those a grants (which all have some early career development goal) not advertised postdoc positions. You so far have provided exactly a case of an advertised post-doc position that had a maximum experience limit.

Comment: @Timrias these "non relevant grants with career development goals" are the backbones of research in all EU countries, contributing a percentage ranging from 30% to 60% of the yearly postdoc position assigned in EU and they are also the blueprint for all the Postdoc positions that will be opened by the various universities&research centers: according to the management "business-crap" language, every postdoc position is for "highly skilled PhDs", no one is hiring "normal" PhDs.
Do not rely on past informations to predict future decisions. It does not work like that in politics ...

Answer (score -1):

Yes he can, but not the direct way.

Such an experienced person can be a great advisor or consultant.

Such a person may be lucky enough to get a guest position in some university (unpaid, but with access to library and all the infrastructure).

I think that this person need to invest a remarkable amount of time in marketing themselves as a possible supporter of PhD/Master student (even as a private tutor), and then they will get possibly some network of contacts (1 to 10% of PhDs will be at least assistant professors in the 5 years after graduation ... ). By the age of 80 this person may have some of his previous contact in a soild, stable academic position: then he/she can discuss about contributing to a research project.